# Reference request: Strong Law of Large Numbers for V-statistics

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

I'm requesting a reference for a Strong Law of Large Numbers theorem for V-statistics (similar to [Hoeffding's 1961 paper](http://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/dr/bitstream/1840.4/2128/1/ISMS_1961_302.pdf) for U-statistics). That is, I am searching for an almost sure convergence theorem, saying 
$$
V_n = \frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{i_1=1}^n \cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^n h\left(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_k}\right) \stackrel{\mbox{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}_n \quad?
$$
where $(X_n)$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random elements with values in some space $\mathcal{X}$ and $h:\mathcal{X}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ is a symmetric kernel with some moment requirements.

If Hoeffdings SSLN for U-statistics can be used to derive this result, an explanation of how this is done, would also more than suffice.

Comment: They are equivalent. Explanation: $n^kV_n=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)U_n+R_n$ where the rest $R_n$ is the sum over every $k$uple with at least two indices equal. There are $O(n^{k-1})$ terms in $R_n$ hence $n^{-k}R_n\to0$ almost surely (under various moment hypotheses) hence you are done.

Comment: Thanks Did, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found four references:

1. Giné, Evarist, and Joel Zinn. "Marcinkiewicz type laws of large numbers and convergence of moments for U-statistics." Probability in Banach Spaces, 8: Proceedings of the Eighth International Conference. Birkhäuser Boston, 1992.
2. [Kondo, Masao, and Hajime Yamato. "Almost sure convergence of a linear combination of U-statistics." Scientiae Mathematicae japonicae 55.3 (2002): 605-613.](http://www.jams.or.jp/scm/contents/Vol-5-6/5-56.pdf)
3. Borovskikh, Yuri Vasilevich. U-statistics in Banach Spaces. VSP, 1996.
4. Korolyuk, Vladimir S., and Yuri V. Borovskich. Theory of U-statistics. Vol. 273. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.